# Visual Studio DLL References - Using Relative Paths And $(ConfigurationName) To Select The Corresponding DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relative-path, buildconfiguration, dll-reference

I have 2 separate Visual Studio C# solutions. One solution contains projects that generate DLL files (class library projects) and the other solution contains projects that depend on the DLL files from the other solution.

I have two questions about adding the DLL files from the first solution as references to each of the projects in the second solution.

1. When I add the DLL files as references (using the Browse option) is
   there a way to use relative directories so that if I move the
   solutions to a different folder I won't have to update the
   references? (Assuming the two solutions are always in the same
   location relative to one another.)

   For example: ....\Solution1\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll
2. If I change the DLL solution's configuration from Release to Debug I
   want the other solution projects to reference the DLLs in the Debug
   folder and vice versa. When adding the DLL files to each project can
   I use something like the Visual Studio macro $(ConfigurationName) in
   the DLL file path so that, depending on whether I build in Debug or
   Release mode, I use the correct DLL file?

   For example:
   ....\Solution1\Project1\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Project1.dll

Thank you.